# Showing m:n relation with combobox and subform (keyword-search)

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

First of all: I am new to access, but started to grasp its possibilities and structure. I know a little bit of VBA, although I do not think this requires coding at all:
I have a many-to-many relationship between two tables, resulting in the (simplified) tables:

```
tblProject
----------
projectNumber*
projectName

tblKeywords
-----------
KeywordID*
Keyword

tblProjectKey
------------
ProjectKeyID*
KeywordID
ProjectNumber
```

Where the * columns are my primary keys.

I want to be able to select a keyword and show a list of ProjectNames that have this correspondence in tblProjectKey.  (Next step would be to select multiple keywords, but that's enough for now).

I made a form based on `tblProjectKey` to use as main form, a subform based on a query `qryProjects` with all fields from `tblProject` and the field `KeywordID` from `tblProjectKeyword`.  The subform ist linked (master and child field) through KeywordID.
I added a combobox on the main form with content `KeywordID`and data set origin `tblKeywords`, and formatted it to show me the keywords' names only (it selects the ID though).

This, however only enables me to show one data set per ProjectKeyID, and I cannot make a selection in the combobox. It shows me each Keyword (highlighted black) with the associated projects, though.

I have spend a lot of time on this and this design is what I came up with after searching the internet, but I do not seem to understand what those properties do exactly and haven't been lucky enough to make it work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.